Does teams-toolkit support the nodejs 4.5 prgramming model in azure functions
Does teams-toolkit support the node-js 4.5 programming model in azure functions?
I'm trying to convert my node-js functions that were generated by the toolkit to use the new  4.5 programming model,but cannot figure out how to get access to the  teamsFxContext.
anyone know if/how this works?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=javascript%2Cwindows%2Cazure-cli&pivots=nodejs-model-v4#extra-inputs-and-outputs

After upgrade to latest Azure Function version, you no longer need to include the TeamsFx binding in your function any more. You can simply remove it.
After remove, you may update your code to obtain the access token from http request header directly.
